# Generation of XML issues

Tags: php, xml

I'm implementing quite easy thing: generating XML,that I going to post to device.
I need something like this:

```
<field1 parameter1='value1' parameter2='value2'/>
<field2 parameter1='value1' parameter2='value2'/>
<field3>
<subfield1>subvalue1</subfied1>
<subfield2>subvalue2</subfied2>
</field3>
```

This is how I generate it.

```
$newConfig.="<field1 parameter1='".$_POST['value1']."' parameter2='".$_POST['value2']."' />\n";
$newConfig.="<field2 parameter1='".$_POST['value1']."' parameter2='".$_POST['value2']."' />\n";
$newConfig.="<field3>
<subfield1>".$_POST['subvalue1']."</subfield1>
<subfield2>".$_POST['subvalue2']."</subfield2>
</field3>";
```

This worked fine and were generating proper value.
But now, when I was testing it with other values, for some reason it generated something like (I look var_dump of config):

```
<field1 parameter1='value1' parameter2='value2'>
   <field2 parameter1='value1' parameter2='value2'>
   <field3>
   <subfield1>subvalue1</subfield1>
   <subfield2>subvalue2</subfield2>
   </field3>
   </field2>
</field1>
```

values have letters, numbers, points and @.
How it is possible? What can cause it?

**UPDATE**
I tried DOMDocument, but output is the same

```
<fields>
  <field1 parameter1="value1" parameter2="value2">
  <field2 parameter1="value1" parameter2="value2">
  <field3>
    <subfield1>subvalue1</subfield1>
    <subfield2>subvalue2</subfield2>
  </field3>
</field2></field1></fields>
```

How is it possible?

**UPDATE1**
I noticed that this problems were only when I inspect element in browser, if I look into source code of page, it is fine.

```
<fields>
  <field1 parameter1="value1" parameter2="value2"/>
  <field2 parameter1="value1" parameter2="value2"/>
  <field3>
    <subfield1>subvalue1</subfield1>
    <subfield2>subvalue2</subfield2>
  </field3>
</fields>
```

So, what is actual xml?
The problem is that I posted it to device, and it worked wrong and I should understand if it is my fault, or no.

Comment: Is the xml here the same as what var_dump is showing?

Comment: For what values you are getting such?

Comment: @benjayhutton I mentioned it: values have letters, numbers, points and @

Comment: Close, because it's not connected with programming? And what else it connected with? I generate xml with php.

Comment: oh, sory @benjayhutton, I meant raveenaniga I didn't understand your question, but may be I answered it in my updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML is invalid. XML documents need to have a single document element node. All other element nodes have to be descendants of that node.

Like this:

```
<documentElement>
  <child>
    <childOfChild>...
  </child>
</documentElement>
```

I imagine some parser tries to repair it. It seems to use the first element node as document element. You might want to change your XML format. Additionally I suggest using an XML API like DOM or XMLWriter. It takes care of the escaping and encoding.

### XMLWriter

XMLWriter works in a serial way, it is most useful if you need to create/output large documents.

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openUri('php://stdout');
$writer->setIndent(2);
$writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$writer->startElement('fields');

$writer->startElement('field1');
$writer->writeAttribute('parameter1', 'value1');
$writer->writeAttribute('parameter2', 'value2');
$writer->endElement();

$writer->startElement('field2');
$writer->writeAttribute('parameter1', 'value1');
$writer->writeAttribute('parameter2', 'value2');
$writer->endElement();

$writer->startElement('field3');

$writer->startElement('subfield1');
$writer->text('subvalue1');
$writer->endElement();

$writer->startElement('subfield2');
$writer->text('subvalue2');
$writer->endElement();

$writer->endElement();

$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fields>
 <field1 parameter1="value1" parameter2="value2"/>
 <field2 parameter1="value1" parameter2="value2"/>
 <field3>
  <subfield1>subvalue1</subfield1>
  <subfield2>subvalue2</subfield2>
 </field3>
</fields>
```

The example writes the XML into standard output. You can use `XMLWriter::openMemory()` and `XMLWriter::outputMemory()` to build the XML in memory and write it into a string.

### DOM

DOM is a tree of node objects, representing the XML. It needs to be done in memory, but it allows for manipulation, not just creation.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->formatOutput = true;

$fields = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('fields'));

$field = $fields->appendChild($document->createElement('field1'));
$field->setAttribute('parameter1', 'value1');
$field->setAttribute('parameter2', 'value2');

$field = $fields->appendChild($document->createElement('field2'));
$field->setAttribute('parameter1', 'value1');
$field->setAttribute('parameter2', 'value2');

$field = $fields->appendChild($document->createElement('field3'));

$subfield = $field->appendChild($document->createElement('subfield1'));
$subfield->appendChild($document->createTextNode('subvalue1'));

$subfield = $field->appendChild($document->createElement('subfield2'));
$subfield->appendChild($document->createTextNode('subvalue2'));

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Each node knows its document, so you can encapsulate tasks into functions/methods easily:

```
function addSubFields($parentNode, array $subFields) {
  $document = $parentNode->ownerDocument;
  foreach ($subFields as $name => $text) {
    $subfield = $parentNode->appendChild($document->createElement($name));
    $subfield->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text));
  }
}

addSubFields($field, ['subfield1' => 'value1', 'subfield2' => 'value2']);
```

Comment: That's fine, trying XMLWriter. I'm looking now for possibility to put output into string variable. If you can help me, or when I find this possibility by myself, I'll assept your answer.

Comment: Notice other mistake, may be it is root of problem, but you helped me a little bit so I accepted your answer.

Comment: That's what I mean by "takes care of the escaping and encoding." If values contain special characters like `&`, `<`, `"`, ... they need to be encoded as entities (`&` = `&amp;`, `<` = `&lt;`, ...) or they will break the XML.